# ->getCurrentCategory()->getParentCategory(); but exclude "Default Category" on level1

Tags: magento2

I'm getting the name of parent category of current category

```
public function getCurrentCategoryId()
{
    return $this->layerResolver->get()->getCurrentCategory()->getId();
}


public function getParentCategoryName()
{
    return $this->layerResolver->get()->getCurrentCategory()->getParentCategory();
}
```

in phtml:

```
$currentCategoryId = $this->getCurrentCategoryId();
$parentCategory = $this->getParentCategoryName($currentCategoryId);
```

I use this in sidebar to show name and URL of the parent category.

This works but only for level 2, 3, ... of the category tree.

For level 1 categories, it shows "Default Category".

Is there any way to check if it's a level 1 category and then show something different?
It would be perfect to show name and URL of current category instead of "Default Category" if it's level 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to get category Level :

> $this->layerResolver->get()->getCurrentCategory()->getLevel();

Comment: Thanks, it's $this->layerResolver->get()->getCurrentCategory()->getLevel(); though

Comment: If answer help then mar as solution and upvote, so it help other in community.